# Probabilistic verification of signature schemes like RSA?

Tags: hash, rsa, public-key, signature, modular-arithmetic

I was wondering if there were any verification algorithm in the literature that enables a "probabilistic" verification of well-known signature schemes?

For RSA signature verification for example, is there any way to verify $s^e = H(m) \mod N$ in a fast way but with a certain "error" probability ?

If not for RSA, for any other schemes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every signature scheme has some nonzero forgery probability: if there are $n$ distinct possible signatures, this forgery probability is always *at least* $1/n$, because a forger could just try signatures uniformly at random.  But sometimes $n$ is so large that $1/n$ is smaller than it needs to be for confidence, say $1/2^{2048}$ when all you really need is $1/2^{100}$, and we can exploit this to trade off forgery probability for performance.  Here's an example of how, with RSA.

Suppose a signature is not an integer $s$ such that $s^e \equiv H(m) \pmod N$, but rather a pair of integers $(s, k)$ with $s < N$ and $k < N^{e - 1}$ such that $$s^e = H(m) + kN.$$  Then the verifier can verify this equation modulo a secret uniform random $v$-bit prime $r$, $$s^e \equiv H(m) + kN \pmod r.$$  There are $\pi(2^v) - \pi(2^{v-1})$ such primes, and $s^e - h - kN$ has at most $\lceil(\log_2 N^e)/v\rceil$ $v$-bit prime factors, so the probability that $r \mid s^e - h - kN$ is at most $$\frac{\lceil(\log_2 N^e)/v\rceil}{\pi(2^v) - \pi(2^{v-1})}$$ for any fixed $(s, k)$, $h$, and $N$ unless $s^e = h + kN$.  Of course, while the forger can try about $t$ messages to find one whose hash $h$ has a desired property occurring with probability $1/t$, only about $1/2^{2048}$ of them satisfy $s^e = h + kN$ if $N \approx 2^{2048}$, so the forger has no hope of finding those.

For $v = 128$, we have $$\pi(2^v) - \pi(2^{v - 1}) \approx \frac{2^{128}}{\log 2^{128}} - \frac{2^{127}}{\log 2^{127}} \approx 2^{120},$$ and for $e = 3$ and $N \approx 2^{2048}$, we have $\lceil(\log_2 N^e)/v\rceil = 48$, so the forgery probability is at most about $1/2^{114}$.

Obviously, the verifier can choose independent primes $r_1, r_2, r_3, \dots$ to lower the forgery probability further; the verifier can also reuse the primes for multiple verifications to save effort, as long as they remain secret.

This scheme is not particularly attractive unless $e$ is very small: even for $e = 3$, it triples the size of the signature.  It is most attractive for Rabin-type signatures with $e = 2$, which are, of course, qualitatively different from RSA-type signatures (and largely better all around *except* in being deployed anywhere!).

To my knowledge, this idea was first published by [Bernstein in 1997](https://groups.google.com/group/sci.crypt/msg/840e777ec0fc5679), and is mentioned in his [summary paper](https://cr.yp.to/papers.html#rwsota) on modular root signature schemes discussing many variations on the themes of RSA and Rabin–Williams signatures.

Comment: Squeamish, does the scheme in your answer have some probability of error in the verification? Anyway, could you please point some (others) signature schemes where the probability of verification of a well well-known signature isn't zero?

Comment: This will sometimes accept a forgery, but with probability small enough not to matter as long as the prime $r$ is large enough or you use enough independent primes.  This will never reject a valid signature.

Comment: I'm just wondering: if schemes with a small probability of forgery are acceptable, why not with some small probability of reject valid signed?

Comment: Of course, _every_ signature scheme accepts a forgery with some probability—if there are $n$ possible signatures then the forgery probability is always _at least_ $1/n$.  There are some signature schemes that may _fail_ when making a signature, but if randomized you can just start over with independent randomization when this happens.  However, it would be rather curious for a signature scheme to sometimes _reject_ a _valid_ signature, and I've never heard of such a scheme.  If you had one, you could just try verifying the signature and start over if verification fails.